# How to change the root folder on the hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, hosting, web-hosting

The site is written in Laravel, when you transfer the site to hosting, all access to ccs, js and photos is done at the link example.com/public/app.css instead of example.com/app.css

.htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD3gB.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The server gives an error, the pages open, but the path to the files must be entered through the public, as you change the root folder for files, so as not to change their entire path to the public